# Get keys of pandas.Series.value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

I use `pandas.Series.value_counts` to count gender of users. But I also need to get the keys of a result to draw a plot and use keys as a label of the plot.

For example the result of `data.gender.value_counts()` is:

```
female     6700
male       6194
brand      5942
unknown    1117
```

And I need to get a list `['female', 'male', 'brand', 'unknown']` as well and keep the order.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [165]: s
Out[165]:
female     6700
male       6194
brand      5942
unknown    1117
Name: value_counts, dtype: int64

In [166]: s.index.tolist()
Out[166]: ['female', 'male', 'brand', 'unknown']
```

Plot:

```
In [169]: s.plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[169]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xd659da0>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
for key, value in data.gender.value_counts().to_dict().items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

```
labels = data.gender.keys()
# or labels = data.gender.index.tolist()
sizes = data.gender.values
```